# Why do Malwares such as Karkoff create and store log files?

Tags: security, malware

I am discovering computer security principles and came across malwares and saw that some of them create and store log files...any insights regarding this matter?

Answer (score 0):

After some research on various malwares, the best analysis was that the attackers generate log files to keep track of the commands executed and sometimes with timestamps to keep track of the time too..